# Drupal 7 Weform 4 attach file message stays even though correct size file is updated

Tags: webforms, files

I have set a file size limit of 4mb for the file type field.

Current behavior
When a file greater than 4mb is attached (10mb.jpg) and upload button is clicked, there is a message shown that mentions.
"The specified file 10mb.jpg could not be uploaded. The file is 10 MB exceeding the maximum file size of 4 MB..

[image]

Now when a file size of less than suggested limit and extensions ( 182kbs - 800px-pizigani_1367_chart_10mb.jpg) is attached and upload button hit, the message still stays and does not go away.

[image]

Expected Behavior:
On attaching and hitting the upload button for the file of correct size, the error message should not be displayed.

Let me know if this has been rectified in a later release or is still occurring for others.

Note: If the upload button is not hit and directly the webform is submitted, the functionality does work fine. Thus there seems to be an issue in client side validation.

Comment: what is the file size of:  800px-pizigani_1367_chart_10mb.jpg

Comment: Check the console for JS errors

Comment: @user5482 182kbs

Comment: @Clive No JS errors in chrome console

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked PHP's own maximum upload file size?

Default in php.ini is usually this:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

You can check your own site's setting at your sites `/admin/reports/status/php`

Comment: The issue is in regards to the misleading error message generated irrespective of the file size. If a client side error is generated for a greater file size then it should go away when that error is rectified and not stay there. Thanks.

Comment: If you change the php.ini, please remember to reload/restart the webservice, and maybe even clear the Drupal caches.

Comment: Now I see that you also filed a bug report in the Webform Module's issue queue (https://www.drupal.org/node/2428073). I suppose you have solved your problem now - great!

Comment: Nah Its not resolved yet, we will see when we get an update with core and check if its still exist to fill a bug with core.

Comment: Good luck! I hope your webform works properly now that you have corrected the underlying configurations.